# Interpreting outputs of my neural network

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I have tried to train a neural network in matlab,first of all I have build the ANN as follow

```
net = feedforwardnet([30 20 20 ]);
[net ,tr] = train(net , XTRAIN , temp);
```

which produce an ANN with the following architecture:
[image]

then I test my neural network as follow

```
outputsOfTest = sim(net , XTEST);
```

the `outputsOfTest` is a vector represent the output of neural network testing, usually some the elements of`outputsOfTest` are negative values , for example the `outputsOfTest` will be something like this `[-.34 1.17 .17]`.

So How to interpret this output? what are negative values indicate to? which class the testing data will belong based on this output?

1. Should I take the greatest value as an indicator to the class that testing data will belong to? 

    for example if I have the output vector `[-2  .5  1]` , which is the greatest value is 1, So the class that testing data belong to is class 3
2. Should I take the greatest value in magnitude (taking the absolute value) ? 
    for example if I have the output vector `[-2 .5 1]` , which is the greatest value in it's magnitude is the first element, So the class that testing data belong to is class 1.

Note: sometimes the sum of the elements of`outputsOfTest` exceed one, the sum of the elements may reach 2.5, does this normal?

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394027/interpret-the-output-of-neural-network-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

Your output layer seems to have a linear activation function. Therefor your output vectors components have values that are not restricted to be between 0 and 1. For classification you should use a softmax activation function:

[image: softmax]

([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function))
The use of softmax results in vector components which have values between 0 and 1 and which sum to 1 for each vector. So basically you get a probability distribution over your classes. The [Matlab help](http://de.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/softmax.html) has an image showing the effects (left input, right after softmax):

[image: softmax matlab]

There's more information about it in the [UFDL Tutorial](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/SoftmaxRegression/).

From what I could find, the following code change might work in Matlab:

```
net = feedforwardnet([30 20 20]);
net.layers{4}.transferFcn='softmax';
[net ,tr] = train(net , XTRAIN , temp);
```